# Cmake compile all c++ files in directory with VTK dependency

Tags: c++, compilation, cmake, makefile, vtk

I have a main file and two classes in C++, all of which use VTK libraries.

I know how to compile one file, how should my CMakeLists look like to compile them all?

Example of the code:

Main:

```
#include <vtkImageData.h>
#include <vtkMetaImageReader.h>
#include <vtkSmartPointer.h>
#include "ClassA.h"
#include "ClassB.h"
```

ClassA.cpp:

```
#include "ClassA.h"
```

ClassB.cpp:

```
#include "ClassB.h"
```

ClassA.h:

```
#include <vector>
#include "vtkImageData.h"
```

ClassB.h:

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include "vtkImageData.h"
#include "vtkMetaImageWriter.h"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `CMakeLists.txt` could look like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

PROJECT(MyProject)

find_package(VTK REQUIRED)
include(${VTK_USE_FILE})

add_executable(MyExecutable main.cpp ClassA.cpp ClassB.cpp)

target_link_libraries(MyExecutable ${VTK_LIBRARIES})
```